# How to use `homebrew install --head` without first uninstalling?

Tags: homebrew

`brew install --head <formula>` installs a formula from `master` (usually). But it feels useless to me, because it fails if you've already got that formula installed due to a link conflict error. (Not even `--force` works.) Therefore you always have to do `brew unlink <formula>` first, or `uninstall` entirely.

I would have expected there to be a way to install a formula without linking it somehow, but apparently not.

Ultimately what I want is to have two copies installed, one the proper release, and one built from master. But the proper one should always have the link. (I would have like to have had another link like `/usr/local/bin/<formula>_HEAD`, but that's another issue.)

As a workaround, I can copy the formula and give at new name, but that seems gross, and you can't have a "`--head`-only" formula it seems, so I'd have to keep the version info up to date in the copy as well.

Maybe I need a totally separate installation of Homebrew? But that seems like overkill.

Comment: with one symlink, you can always have one actual installation, which leads to the link, unlink process, right?

Comment: I dont see any issue of doing `brew link` to link which installation you prefer. If you have a better proposal, you are welcome to submit to `homebrew/brew` repo.

Comment: @chenrui: Right, but you need to do `brew unlink` first to unlink the non-head version. I think what I'm looking for is something like `brew install --no-link`, which would be implied by `--head`. Yeah, probably worth a GH issue.